# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым при описании технических характеристик

Tags: тире

Часто вижу, что всякие технические издания не ставят тире между подлежащим и сказуемым при описании технических характеристик. Предложения примерно такие:

1. Его длина (—) 28 метров.
2. Дисплей: 5 дюймов, Full HD, соотношение сторон (—) 18:9.
3. При весе в 250 грамм его длина (—) 50 мм.

Я же правильно понимаю, что во всех подобных случаях тире должно быть, ведь оно заменяет слова «является», «составляет» и т. д.?

Или всё же можно не ставить?

Answer (score 3):

Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится по строгим предписаниям для фиксированных языковых ситуаций, такое тире обозначает паузу в речи, которая вносит выразительность или иногда удобство в восприятие речи при «пропущенных» связках или словах в неполных предложениях.
Взгляните на два примера, где подлежащее и сказуемое являются существительными в именительном падеже:

— Что вы, как литературовед, думаете о Пушкине?
— Пушкин — великий писатель. (Выразительная пауза в пафосном предложении.)

— В ваших работах прослеживаются нотки упрека в адрес Пушкина.
— Конечно, Пушкин великий писатель, но у меня есть претензии к его творчеству. (Отсутствие пафоса и выразительной паузы.)

Даже такие предложения, как: «Портрет этот — единственное живописное изображение дочери Анны Петровны Керн», могут быть написаны без тире , если мы передаем речь школьника, который невыразительно читает это предложение.

Как в реальной жизни мы делаем паузу в речи, когда чувствуем, что без нее возможно неудобство восприятия или даже недопонимание, или когда просто хотим произнести выразительно, так и на письме эти функции восполняет это тире.
Возвращаясь к вашему вопросу, никто ведь не станет произносить выразительно сухие характеристики из документации, но даже в разговорном стиле люди могут сделать короткую паузу для удобства восприятия на месте пропущенной связки, так что такое тире является факультативным.

В справочнике Розенталя есть примечание на эту тему:
«В специальной литературе при характеристике предмета тире в этом случае часто не ставится: Грузоподъёмность крана 2,5 тонны, вылет стрелы 5 метров; Температура плавления золота 1063°С».

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html) (§ 5.4)

Comment: От меня плюсик. Ничего, хорошо написано,  даже не ожидала. Успехи делаете. "Конечно, Пушкин велИкий писатель, // но у меня есть претензии к его твОрчеству". Здесь точно паузы нет, влияет структура сложного предложения. Надо было только ссылку из Розенталя  еще дать на техническую речь, чтобы не было претензий.

Comment: Спасибо. Я добавлю это маленькое примечание из Розенталя.

Comment: @JimKorbett Хороший ответ — я тоже поддержу. Надо, думаю, кое-что подправить. 1. Мне кажется, Вы ошиблись в самом начале ответа: _Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым **не ставится**..._ Надо бы "ставится". 2. Для обозначения градуса можете скопировать: **°С** (у Вас — 1063о С). 3. Считаю, что в ответе необходимо дать ссылку: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, спасибо за поддержку. Я имел ввиду, что не ставится исходя из одних только строгих предписаний, а ставится исходя из учета еще других характеристик языковой ситуации. Градус и ссылку на Розенталя добавлю.